# GUI won't load, but the desktop background loads. Can't access the terminal

Tags: gnome, 14.04, gui

Having trouble with the Ubuntu GUI. I can log in just fine (see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xj77h.jpg))... everything looks normal there. But as soon as I put in my password, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCFWx.jpg). I tried a few different troubleshooting keyboard commands (ctrl+alt+t, crtl+alt+delete), and only the latter worked. I can interact with that window just fine, except I am unable to resize or move it.

The first time I logged in, I got a dialog box that said, "Ubuntu has experienced an internal error. Send error report?" Doesn't say anything now.

Yes I tried restarting it.

Thanks a bunch, 
Michael

EDIT: Trying to start a guest session leads to the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should go to the console with <kbd>CTRL+ALT+F1</kbd> and try restarting the desktop manager.

Try:

```
sudo service lightdm
```

or

```
sudo /etc/init.d/gdm restart
```

Or try stopping them. Also look in log:

```
less /var/log/Xorg.*.log
```

In CentOS this can happen if you go very low on space or have some power management problems. Maybe it's the same with Ubuntu.

After running the restart thing you may return to the GUI with <kbd>CTRL+ALT+F7</kbd>.

Comment: Hiya Bodo, thanks for your reply. I tried using the console, but I'm not entirely sure how to proceed from [here](http://m.imgur.com/AJ9xnYJ) How do I login? I tried a bunch of different things: Michael, michael, Michael P Lane, Michael\ P\ Lane, Guest, guest... nothing worked. =(

Comment: So, while in the console accessed with CTRL ALT F1 you have to login with the username, not the name. From what you wrote there, I bet micahel is your name. Usually the first one that is present in the right corner of your status bar of Ubuntu. If you remember, it's probably the first name you had, near the clock in the top bar.

Comment: Try michael (all lowercase). Also, after you type username (you can see what you type) and hit enter, without saying you if the name was good or no, it will ask for a password. You will NOT see it as you type it (like when you SUDO or SU). Just type it blindly and hit enter, and than it will tell you if it was OK or not. If it does not work and you really can't remember, you'll have to boot the ubuntu install cd /usb and try reading logs and fixing things from its live / "try" mode.

Comment: It worked! I did what you said (sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm restart). If gave me [this](http://imgur.com/pj2A9Wj). It seems like it's too-politely asking for input from me, because it zoomed through that sequence real quick and has been sitting at that point for 5 minutes. I tried to ctrl+c out of it, but that was a mistake, because it gave me a screen with a blinking underscore afterwards and no other options but to ctrl+alt+f5 back into the console.